# How do I make a method loop every 7 days at the same time based on real time?

Tags: java

pastebin.com/zgedMeaa I've got it to loop at a certain time. What I need to do now is make it so that when I start the script it will finish at 12AM Monday 4 weeks later. Also; When I run my current script (Pastebin Link) The output is this: 1.001495E7, There is letters and that doesn't seem right. Could you tell me why it doesn't show the 14.95% Interest added onto the 100k?

Comment: Use Timer or a scheduler (like Quartz).

Comment: Use quartz http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: Also, don't base your solution on 604800000 milliseconds - some weeks have more milliseconds and some weeks have less. For example when the clocks go forwards or backwards, you would end up with your code kicking in on Sunday at 11pm on one week.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule "Tasks" by the java.util.Timer class

Comment: I'm a noob with java, I should of added so do you have a little snippit or something, or a skype we can chat on? I need a mentor for java aswell.

Comment: @user2256632 Mirko has pointed you in the right direction, now google what he said, or find the documentation, and there will be snippets for you right there.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args){
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
      depositInterest();
     }
   }, 604800000);
 }

I've got that, and it is working (I tested it on 1 second). But it only prints it once and then doesn't do anything. How do I make it loop every x (x = defined amount of milliseconds)? Also, how come when it prints to the system.out it is printing this number 1.001495E7 It has the letter E in it, and is in a decimal?

Answer (score 0):

What you want, is the famous Unix **cron**, a scheduling task. In java for instance [cron4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/). Instead of the java Timer cron has a simple declarative configuration and is calendar/clock oriented.

Quartz has a [CronTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/WeeklyTrigger) too.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zgedMeaa

I've got it to loop at a certain time. What I need to do now is make it so that when I start the script it will finish at 12AM Monday 4 weeks later.

Also; When I run my current script (Pastebin Link) The output is this: 1.001495E7, There is letters and that doesn't seem right. Could you tell me why it doesn't show the 14.95% Interest added onto the 100k?

Comment: @maloney

Do you have skype, I need to speak to you about something important. Getting a degree java programming and stuff like that.

Comment: `1.001495E7 == 10_014_950` (scientific notation)